# Calling web host directly with HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core

This is mostly an academic question, but it might have some real world value in my project.

Having defined a web host in a web project (dotnet core 3.1), is there any way to call this host directly with a HttpContext?

I assume there might be a service somewhere to override to allow me to just run the HttpContext processing part of the pipeline, without having an actual web server running - but I can't quite find it. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement clearly. Do you mean you want to run a specific service or program to send request to web api directly? Why you create a program.cs and call the web service in a main method?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have a defined host, but I just want to run the part of it which works on HttpContext/HttpRequest. As I said, it's mostly academical - I wonder if it can be done (without too much fuss).

Comment: Do you mean you want to call the web api in  web api host application?